# Incorrect syntax near 'UPDATE'

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables X and Y.

X is like

| D100_PTRSORID | D100_LIB17 | D100_LIB18 | D100_LIB19 | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15000 | 2000 | 75000 | ... |
| 11 | 12500 | 2500 | 7000 | ... |
| 12 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The amounts in the fields `D100_LIBXX` are not correct. I would like to update these amounts thanks to table Y, which is like

| GAD_PTRSORID | GAD_CODE | GAD_CAPITAL | ... | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 201** | 11000 | ... | ... |
| 10 | 202** | 1500 | ... | ... |
| 10 | 203** | 8500 | ... | ... |
| 11 | 201** | 12500 | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

`D100_LIB17` is related to `GAD_CODE` = '201**'

`D100_LIB18` is related to `GAD_CODE` = '202**'

`D100_LIB19` is related to `GAD_CODE` = '203**'

I started to write this following script for updating the data but I have an error at the "UPDATE" level (underlined in red) with error message **Incorrect syntax near 'UPDATE'. Expected end-of-input -or- [...]**

```
SELECT * FROM X

UPDATE Xx 
SET Xx.D100_LIB17=Yy.GAD_CAPITAL
FROM X Xx
INNER JOIN Y Yy 
ON Xx.D100_PTRSORID = Yy.GAD_PTRSORID and Yy.GAD_CODE = '201**'

SELECT * FROM X
```

Comment: This seems to be SQL, no PL/SQL; and if those three statement are in one script, do you actually have statement separators (typically a semicolon) or a slash between them? (Which client you are using, and how you run the script, might make a difference too.) Oracle also doesn't allow `UPDATE ... FROM`, but you can use a corelated update.

Comment: @AlexPoole do you mean that this piece of code does not work with PL/SQL? I checked on internet how to use the UPDATE statement for PL/SQL for writing this script... I don't put "statement separators". Should I ? The rest of the script (creation of table X and Y works fine without separators). Could you maybe suggest me a script which works please?

Comment: you haven't shown the rest of the script, or said how (or in which client) you're running it. You might be running the create statements individually, or with slashes after them. The vague error your client is giving suggests it's seeing the update as part of the previous select though.

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably because you aren't terminating the individual statements; depending on your client and settings, that's usually done with a semicolon statement separator:

```
SELECT * FROM X;

UPDATE ... ;

SELECT * FROM X;
```

or slash, on a line on its own (particularly for PL/SQL blocks):

```
SELECT * FROM X
/

UPDATE ...
/

SELECT * FROM X
/
```

Your update syntax isn't valid for Oracle though - you can't `UPDATE ... FROM` a query. You can use a correlated update instead:

```
UPDATE X Xx
SET Xx.D100_LIB17 = (
  SELECT Yy.GAD_CAPITAL
  FROM Y Yy 
  WHERE Yy.GAD_PTRSORID = Xx.D100_PTRSORID
  AND Yy.GAD_CODE = '201**'
);
```

That will update all rows in X, not just those that are different; and if you have a row in X without a matching row in Y that will be set to null.

You can also update multiple columns at once, and you might want to consider using a `MERGE` rather than an `UPDATE`, e.g.:

```
MERGE INTO X Xx
USING (
  SELECT GAD_PTRSORID,
    MAX(CASE GAD_CODE WHEN '201**' THEN GAD_CAPITAL END) AS D100_LIB17,
    MAX(CASE GAD_CODE WHEN '202**' THEN GAD_CAPITAL END) AS D100_LIB18,
    MAX(CASE GAD_CODE WHEN '203**' THEN GAD_CAPITAL END) AS D100_LIB19
  FROM Y
  GROUP BY GAD_PTRSORID
) Yy
ON (Yy.GAD_PTRSORID = Xx.D100_PTRSORID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  Xx.D100_LIB17 = Yy.D100_LIB17,
  Xx.D100_LIB18 = Yy.D100_LIB18,
  Xx.D100_LIB19 = Yy.D100_LIB19;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bea473e5b7904a22eeea3c347e3dfd79) - notice that two values in that demo still end up as null, because the sample data only has one row for ID 11. If you always have all the matching data that might not be an issue. If you don't then you can use `COALESCE()` to keep the existing value for columns without a corresponding value in Y.

You could expand the merge to insert missing rows, of you have IDs in Y with no matching row in X. Or define X as a pivot view of Y so you don't have to maintain the same data in two places.

Comment: I almost never use `UPDATE` in Oracle any more.  `MERGE` is just so much more appropriate in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: @AlexPoole I replaced my script by the 2 scripts you proposed to me but I receive a new error message **Oracle Database Error. table or view does not exist** . Do you see why?

Comment: @Nassim - your earlier comment suggested the tables were created in the same script so you'd still need to do that, if this is an assignment and they aren't supposed to exist before you start. Or maybe you didn't change the X/Y names to your real table names.

Comment: I created 2 tables called X and Y thanks to the WITH statement. `WITH X AS (...) , Y as (...) SELECT * FROM X;` This part works fine. And below this script, I added you piece of code. Is it the right way to do this?

Comment: @Nassim - `WITH` doesn't create a table; it's a common table expression or subquery factoring clause ([see the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__GUID-DFD72C34-5CED-4F6D-BA6D-829BE525CF92)), and is treated "as either an inline view or as a temporary table", that only exist sat all for the duration of the query it's part of. Although you can use a CTE within an update, it doesn't make sense to try to update the result of that subquery.

Comment: You now seem to be saying that the results of the two `WITH` subqueries are different; so you'd need to modify those or update the real base tables those refer to. Without knowing what those subqueries are doing, what the base data looks like, or why they are different - including whether they should be, and if not which is correct, and why - it's hard to advise how you should proceed. You could ask another question with all that information, but it's probably better to ask whoever set you this task.

Comment: Very clear thank you. I wanted to make a kind of test with the X and Y tables before editing the "big" table. Does it mean that I cannot work on a temporary table for testing my modifications?

Comment: Not really with a CTE. If you have permission you could create a global or [(if you're on Oracle 18c+) private](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c) temporary table, which you could populate from the base tables and then update and query that.